# Optimize Performance of Cross Apply between Multi Statement Table Valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization, sql-server-2016

I have the following query that select the best movements to do from a list of sources. The source list is evaluated with the first table valued function. Then, for each source, i try find the possible destinations using the second table valued function.

They do their job, but the whole query takes too much time (some minutes). Of course the main issue is calling the GetDestinations() function for every source, because it's a multi statement table valued function. So I'm trying to find suggestion or ideas on how to rewrite/improve this behavior. Changing the GetDestinations to an inline would be very hard and it would produce a very unreadable query, so i'm trying to avoid it even if i know it's probably the best solution.

Thank you very much in advance!

**EDIT**: Thanks for all the tips. I did manage to improve a little bit the main query, but the problem remain in the GetDestinations of which i posted the plan now. I will try to inline it and see how much that improve the performance. For a scenario description, the StorageLocation table contains 20k rows, the GetSources() functions returns an average of 5k records, and the GetDestination() returns just a few but it's executed 5k times.

```
    ;WITH sources AS -- Get source locations
        (
            SELECT s.Id_StorageLocation,
                    s.FillingRate,
                    s.NumStockUnit,
                    s.OperationRotation
            FROM Client.ufn_GetHousekeepingSourceLocations(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) s 
            WHERE s.NumTaskDrop = 0
                AND s.NumTaskPick = 0 
                AND s.FillingRate <= @MaxFullSource
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Shipping.PreStagingAreaStorageLocation a  WHERE a.Id_StorageLocation = s.Id_StorageLocation)
                AND (s.LastDropTime IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(HOUR, s.LastDropTime, GETDATE()) >= @MinHoursFromLastOperation)
        ),
        availableRoutes AS -- Get possible routes joining sources with every destination
        (
            SELECT 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.Id_StorageLocation ORDER BY d.FillingRate DESC ) AS RouteRank
                ,s.Id_StorageLocation       AS Id_Source
                ,s.FillingRate              AS SourceFillRate
                ,s.NumStockUnit             AS SourceStockNum
                ,d.Id_StorageLocation       AS Id_Destination
                ,d.FillingRate              AS DestinationFillRate
                ,d.NumEmptyPositions        AS DestinationFreePos
            FROM sources s 
            CROSS APPLY Client.ufn_GetHousekeepingDestinationLocations(s.Id_StorageLocation, 'False', 'False') d
            WHERE d.NumTaskPick = 0 
                AND d.NumTaskDrop = 0
                AND d.FillingRate >= @MinFullDestination
                AND (d.LastPickTime IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(HOUR, d.LastPickTime, GETDATE()) >= @MinHoursFromLastOperation)
                AND s.FillingRate <= d.FillingRate
                AND d.OperationRotation = s.OperationRotation
        )
        SELECT
            m.RouteRank,
            m.Id_Source,
            m.SourceFillRate,
            m.SourceStockNum,
            m.Id_Destination,
            m.DestinationFillRate,
            m.DestinationFreePos
        FROM availableRoutes m
        WHERE m.RouteRank = 1
        ORDER BY m.SourceFillRate
```

Main Query Plan
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkl9MNcfs

Get Destinations Plan
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyPlbfszo

Comment: For performance related questions we need to see the table definitions, index definitions and the execution plan (Paste The Plan).

Comment: Without visibility of what these functions are doing and the tables, indexes and execution plan, this is unanswerable. I would start with the divide and conquer approach. Also having an `or` criteria that involves an *unsargable expression* is not helping, you need to apply the function to the other side of the equality.

Comment: Tip - instead of posting a picture of an execution plan, read the comment above and Google "Paste The Plan" if it's unfamiliar. An image of an execution plan is useless, the planxml is required which contains a wealth of information about statistics, operators, scans, estimates, index usage etc. The image does show however the bulk of time is spent in the TVF, but this is a black box. no one is going to look at the huge amount of query dumped in your question, you need a *minimal* reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate the infos and the patience. Hope the execution plan is fine now, even if you may be more interested in the one of the 2 functions i guess. My main question is actually if there is a better way of doing this operation (cross applying the two functions), or if my only choice is optimizing the functions, in particular the GetDestination().

Comment: @DanielUgolini the point is, performance cannot be determined by the query alone because SQL is declarative, i.e. you are describing the results you want to the engine, but you are not telling it how to obtain those results. So we can't just give tips on query structure to improve performance because it doesn't generally work that way.

Comment: However one thing I can say, is that if your functions are multi-line table values functions, then yes they may hurt performance. You should aim for inline table values functions.

Comment: But looking at your query plan, the most expensive item is a clustered index scan which is pretty bad.. and implies you are missing indexes.

Comment: Another "trick" for multi-CTE issues is to split out the results from the first CTE into a temp table and then carry on with your query, as that allows SQL Server to generate 2 execution plans which can sometimes allow for better performance.

Comment: You could definitely benefit from some index tuning, eg an index on `Id_StorageLocation` may be beneficial. However even though you have table scans, the bulk of the time spent is not scanning the table but on the rbar application of your functions and this is where you should focus your time, although you have not provided this code so suggestions are not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the plan provided I concur with others that you probably want an index on the `PreStaging' table.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test ON Shipping.PreStagingAreaStorageLocation (Id_StorageLocation)
```

As there is no way to distinguish between how much time is really spent in the one ufn or the other one, dumping the results from the leading one in a temp-table and then going from there will allow you to time how long each one takes and then focus on which one to optimize.

I also rewrote the non SARG-able `WHERE` parts.
Read: Don't use `WHERE functionX(field) > constant` when you can use `WHERE field > functionY(constant)`, the former requires applying `functionX()` to every record being processed, the latter only requires `functionY()` to be executed once during startup. Additionally, if there is an index on `field`, the query engine can only take (proper) advantage of it using the second syntax.

```
-- get list of sources first and put in temp-table
SELECT s.Id_StorageLocation,
       s.FillingRate,
       s.NumStockUnit,
       s.OperationRotation
  INTO #sources
  FROM Client.ufn_GetHousekeepingSourceLocations(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) s 
 WHERE s.NumTaskDrop = 0
   AND s.NumTaskPick = 0 
   AND s.FillingRate <= @MaxFullSource
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                     FROM Shipping.PreStagingAreaStorageLocation a  
                    WHERE a.Id_StorageLocation = s.Id_StorageLocation)
   AND (s.LastDropTime IS NULL 
            OR 
        -- DATEDIFF(HOUR, s.LastDropTime, GETDATE()) >= @MinHoursFromLastOperation
        s.LastDropTime < DateAdd(HOUR, -@MinHoursFromLastOperation, GETDATE())
       );
```

This is bit of a gamble as I can't tell if this is applicable to your situation but assuming that the `Id_StorageLocation` field is unique in the above recordset, we can rewrite your CROSS APPLY to what i think would be something mildly less costly, especially as `ufn_GetHousekeepingDestinationLocations` is a multi-statement function anyway and thus (probably) can't be inlined. As such I'm adding the UNIQUE keyword to make sure this is a valid assumption.

Also, even without the need for checking for uniqueness, adding an index here will make sure the optimizer will at least have a good idea about the number of lines in this table.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx1_sources ON #sources (Id_StorageLocation);
```

The actual query:

```
;WITH 
    availableRoutes AS -- Get possible routes joining sources with every destination
    (
        SELECT 
            -- ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.Id_StorageLocation ORDER BY d.FillingRate DESC ) AS RouteRank,
             s.Id_StorageLocation       AS Id_Source
            ,s.FillingRate              AS SourceFillRate
            ,s.NumStockUnit             AS SourceStockNum
            ,d.Id_StorageLocation       AS Id_Destination
            ,d.FillingRate              AS DestinationFillRate
            ,d.NumEmptyPositions        AS DestinationFreePos
        FROM #sources s 
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
                       FROM Client.ufn_GetHousekeepingDestinationLocations(s.Id_StorageLocation, 'False', 'False') d
                      WHERE d.NumTaskPick = 0 
                        AND d.NumTaskDrop = 0
                        AND d.FillingRate >= @MinFullDestination
                        -- AND (d.LastPickTime IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(HOUR, d.LastPickTime, GETDATE()) >= @MinHoursFromLastOperation)
                        AND (d.LastPickTime IS NULL OR d.LastPickTime < DateAdd(HOUR, -@MinHoursFromLastOperation, GETDATE()))
                        AND s.FillingRate <= d.FillingRate
                        AND d.OperationRotation = s.OperationRotation
                      ORDER BY d.FillingRate DESC)
    )
    SELECT
        -- m.RouteRank,
        m.Id_Source,
        m.SourceFillRate,
        m.SourceStockNum,
        m.Id_Destination,
        m.DestinationFillRate,
        m.DestinationFreePos
    FROM availableRoutes m
    -- WHERE m.RouteRank = 1
    ORDER BY m.SourceFillRate
```

If `ufn_GetHousekeepingSourceLocations()` does return doubled `Id_StorageLocation` records then you'll need to un-comment the ranking part again. I can't really tell if the added `TOP 1 .. ORDER BY d.FillingRate DESC` will actually help then. The only way to find out is by trying it out.

---

UPDATE: looking at the code from `ufn_GetHousekeepingSourceLocations()` as learned from the newly added query plan:

- You are using `LEFT JOIN Storage.StorageLocationStockProperties slsp` yet in the `WHERE` it says `AND slsp.Id_Item = @Id_Item`

  - This implicitly makes the `LEFT JOIN` an `INNER JOIN`, probably best to get rid of the `LEFT` then.
  - This is mostly 'style' but I tend to put filters on joined tables in the `ON` clause, it makes things more easy to read IMHO.
- You use a `DISTINCT` on an already `GROUP BY`d recordset, that does not really make sense IMHO
- I wonder if `AND ISNULL(sz.Id_LogicalArea, 0) NOT IN (1)` wouldn't be better written as `AND ISNULL(sz.Id_LogicalArea, 0) <> 1`
- The use of the table variables @QualityStatusList and @LotStatusList is interesting here in that I'd normally advice against an `IN()` and prefer to have it `JOIN`, however, given that you only need it in 1 side of an `OR` statement makes it a bit more ... challenging, nevertheless, it can (and IMHO should) be done.
- IMHO there is something fishy going on with your usage of the `Inventory.Item` table and @Id_Item

  - You ask for `TOP 1` but you don't specify an `ORDER BY`, as such you risk getting a randomly different one for each call of the function. Maybe this is fine?
  - Later on you fetch `EquivalenceDays` in order to calculate the `ExpireDateMin/Max` for every Item individually yet for the filtering on `Storage.StorageZone` you base yourself on that one single random @Id_Item !??!

Doing some quick refactoring I end up with:

```
SELECT TOP 1
       @Id_SourceLocationType       = sl.Id_StorageLocationType,
       @OperationRotation           = ISNULL(sl.OperationRotation, 0),
       @Id_Item                     = it.Id,
       @Id_ItemPreferredStorageArea = it.Id_PreferredArea
  FROM Storage.StorageLocation sl
  JOIN Storage.StorageLocationStockProperties slsp 
    ON slsp.Id_StorageLocation = sl.Id
  JOIN Inventory.Item it 
    ON it.Id = slsp.Id_Item
 WHERE sl.Id = @Id_SourceLocation

INSERT INTO @LotStatusList  ( Id )
SELECT DISTINCT Id_LotStatus
  FROM Storage.StorageLocationStockProperties
 WHERE Id_StorageLocation = @Id_SourceLocation 
   AND Id_LotStatus IS NOT NULL

INSERT INTO @QualityStatusList ( Id )
SELECT DISTINCT Id_QualityStatus
  FROM Storage.StorageLocationStockProperties
 WHERE Id_StorageLocation = @Id_SourceLocation 
   AND Id_QualityStatus IS NOT NULL

SELECT @SourceLocationStockUnitHeight = MAX(StockUnitHeight),
       @SourceLocationStockUnitWeight = MAX(StockUnitWeight)
  FROM Storage.ufn_GetStorageLocationStatus(@Id_SourceLocation, 'true')

SELECT @ExpireDateMax = MIN(supart.ExpireDate), 
       @ExpireDateMin = MAX(supart.ExpireDate)
  FROM Storage.StorageLocation l
  JOIN Storage.StoragePosition sp 
    ON sp.Id_StorageLocation = l.Id
  JOIN Storage.StockUnitPosition sup 
    ON sup.Id_StoragePosition = sp.Id
  JOIN Inventory.StockUnitPart supart 
    ON supart.Id_StockUnit = sup.Id_StockUnit
 WHERE l.Id = @Id_SourceLocation

SELECT sl.Id AS Id_StorageLocation, 
       sl.Name AS Name_StorageLocation,
       slt.Name AS Name_LocationPhysicalType,
       sa.Name AS Name_StorageArea,
       slep.NumStockUnit, 
       slep.NumEmptyPositions,
       slep.NumTaskDrop,
       slep.NumTaskPick, 
       slep.NumTotalPositions,
       CASE WHEN slep.IsFull = 1 THEN 100
         WHEN slep.IsEmpty = 1 THEN 0
         WHEN slep.NumTotalPositions > 0 THEN (slep.NumStockUnit*100)/slep.NumTotalPositions END AS FillingRate,
       slep.LastDropTime,
       slep.LastPickTime,
       MIN(slsp.ExpireDateMin) AS ExpireDateMin,
       MAX(slsp.ExpireDateMax) AS ExpireDateMax,
       sl.OperationRotation,
       sz.Id_StorageArea
  FROM Storage.StorageLocation sl
  
  JOIN Storage.StorageZone sz 
    ON sl.Id_StorageZone = sz.Id
   AND sz.StorageEnabled = 'true'
   -- AND ISNULL(sz.Id_LogicalArea, 0) NOT IN (1)
   AND ISNULL(sz.Id_LogicalArea, 0) <> 1
   AND (
           (@Id_ItemPreferredStorageArea = @Id_StorageArea_Conditioned AND sz.Id_StorageArea = @Id_StorageArea_Conditioned)
        OR (@Id_ItemPreferredStorageArea = @Id_StorageArea_Ambient AND sz.Id_StorageArea IN (@Id_StorageArea_Ambient, @Id_StorageArea_Conditioned))
       )
   
  JOIN Storage.StorageArea sa 
    ON sa.Id = sz.Id_StorageArea
    
  JOIN Storage.StorageLocationPhysicalType slt 
    ON slt.Id = sl.Id_StorageLocationPhisycalType
    
  JOIN Storage.StorageLocationStockProperties slsp 
    ON sl.Id = slsp.Id_StorageLocation
    
  LEFT OUTER JOIN @QualityStatusList qsl -- only needed in 1 side of an OR construction in the WHERE below => LEFT OUTER JOIN
               ON qsl.Id = slsp.Id_QualityStatus 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN @LotStatusList lsl -- only needed in 1 side of an OR construction in the WHERE below => LEFT OUTER JOIN
               ON lsl.Id = slsp.Id_LotStatus 

  JOIN Storage.StorageLocationExtendedProperties slep 
    ON sl.Id = slep.Id_StorageLocation
    --AND slep.NumTaskDrop + slep.NumTaskDropMoving = 0
    
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Inventory.Item i 
               ON slsp.Id_Item = i.Id
               
 WHERE sl.Id_StorageLocationType = 5 -- Only segregation single SKU (Warehouse location)
   AND sl.StorageDisabled = 'false'
   AND sl.CanStorage = 'true'
   AND sl.MaxWeight > @SourceLocationStockUnitWeight
   AND sl.Clearance >= @SourceLocationStockUnitHeight + IIF(sl.OperationRotation = 1, @LgvClearanceOffsetDriveIn, @LgvClearanceOffsetSelective)
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Shipping.PreStagingAreaStorageLocation prestol WHERE prestol.Id_StorageLocation = sl.Id) --don't include prestaging locations
   AND sl.Id <> @Id_SourceLocation --Do not include source location
   AND (sl.OperationRotation IS NULL OR sl.OperationRotation = @OperationRotation OR @AllowMovementBetweenDifferentRotation = 'True') -- CC1600 No rotation station for now
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Storage.StoragePosition p WHERE (p.RetrievalDisabled = 1 OR p.RetrievalBlocked = 1 ) AND p.Id_StorageLocation = sl.id)
   --Input filters   
   AND 
     (
        (slep.IsEmpty = 'true' AND @ShowEmptyLocations = 'true' AND slep.NumEmptyPositions > 0 AND slep.NumBookedPositions = 0)
        OR 
        (
         slep.IsFull = 'false' 
         AND slep.NumEmptyPositions > 0 
         AND slsp.Id_Item = @Id_Item
         AND qsl.Id IS NOT NULL -- AKA: we found a match in @QualityStatusList
         AND lsl.Id IS NOT NULL -- AKA: we found a match in @LotStatusList
         AND CAST(@ExpireDateMin AS DATE) >= DATEADD(DAY,-i.EquivalenceDays, slsp.ExpireDateMin)
         AND CAST(@ExpireDateMax AS DATE) <= DATEADD(DAY,+i.EquivalenceDays, slsp.ExpireDateMax)
        )
     )
     
  GROUP BY sl.Id, sl.Name, slt.Name, sa.Name, slep.NumStockUnit, slep.NumEmptyPositions, slep.NumTaskDrop, slep.NumTaskPick, slep.NumTotalPositions, 
           slep.LastDropTime, slep.LastPickTime, sl.OperationRotation, sz.Id_StorageArea, slep.IsFull, slep.IsEmpty
```

Depending on the 'need' of the `@Item_Id` construction it shouldn't be too hard to convert all of this into 1 single query and then convert this Mulit Statement Function into a Table Valued Function which would allow for a big boost in performance as the engine (probably) might be able to inline the function in the calling query.

Anyway, looks like an interesting application you're maintaining there =)

PS: Also make sure you define the table variables as having `PRIMARY KEY` on the `Id` field.

Comment: thanks @deroby! this improved a little the performance but the main issue remain the large amount of call on GetDestinations() and i guess the poor optimization on this one. I'll try to work on it, in the meantime i also posted the execution plan.